# Allow one cart item before place order button click or proceed to checkout button click

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to disallow place order if cart item is more than two on click of proceed to checkout or Place Order button click in woocommerce.
I do not want to check it on add to cart validation check, please any one can guide me about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WooCommerce Min/Max Quantities](https://woocommerce.com/products/minmax-quantities/) extension to set a minimum and maximum quantity required to checkout.

or

You can set custom code to your functions.php theme file by using "woocommerce_after_checkout_validation" filter and can use $posted array to check value and set validation,

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'rei_after_checkout_validation');

    function rei_after_checkout_validation( $posted ) {

        // do all your logics here...

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_checkout_button_action(){
     global $woocommerce;
     $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
     $total = 0;
      foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $total = $values['quantity'];       
      }
      if($total>=2){
          ?>
          <a href="//your check out URL" onclick="return false"><?php  _e( 'Check On Out', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>        
          <?php
      }
      else{
          ?>
          <a href="//your check out URL"><?php  _e( 'Check On Out', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>           
          <?php
      }   
}
add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'custom_checkout_button_action');
```

If you are using butto you can change your HTML accordingly to disable button instead of link in above code on check out page before place an order page.